# SIMD: implement _mm256_i8gather, _mm256_i16gather

Tags: c++, intel, simd, avx, avx2

I want to ask a question about SIMD. Intel doesn't offer `gather` functions like: `_mm256_i8gather_epi8, _mm256_i16gather_epi16`.

They should simply do the samiliar things like [_mm256_i32gather_epi32](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=gather&techs=AVX2&expand=2983) and [_mm256_i64gather_epi64](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=gather&techs=AVX2&expand=3081) , but just load 32 `int8_t` or 16 `int16_t`.

How can we implement these functions with `AVX2`?

---

I founded one on Internet: https://gist.github.com/tanakamura/7c159d27f744fc24ff8243522b166820, which is hard and heavily implemented.

Comment: They don't provide the function because, unlike the 32- and 64-bit cases, there is no corresponding CPU instruction that implements it. As you noticed in the example you linked, it would take quite a bit of effort to emulate the same function for the 8- and 16-bit sizes.

Comment: If you don't have to worry about segfaults from reading into an unmapped page (e.g. an i8 or i16 at the very end of a page), then you can unpack to i32 and repack with AND + `vpackusdw`

Comment: N.B. if you had only 16 entries to gather from, you could use `vpshufb` (with some twiddling, you could use `n` shuffles to gather from `n*16` entries). Other than that, I don't see an alternative to joining 2 or 4 `vpgatherdd` instructions.